# R Assign value to column according to value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this

```
 NAME       DIST    
 A          0           
 A          1           
 A          100         
 A          2           
 A          1           
 A          4           
 A          500         
 A          1           
 A          1
```

What I want to do is to find an efficient way of creating a new column NEWNAME such that if DIST > 100 it contains a a name that is equal for all the previous rows

```
 NAME       DIST     NEWNAME
 A          0           A
 A          1           A
 A          100         A
 A          2           A2
 A          1           A2
 A          4           A2
 A          500         A3
 A          1           A3
 A          1           A3
```

I have done it using a for loop but I was looking for a more efficient solution in R style. Below my code using a for loop

```
k <- 0
for(l in 1:length(df$NAME)){
       if(df$DIST[l] >= 100){
                k <- k+1;
                df$NEWNAME[(l):length(df$NAME)] <- paste(df$NAME,k,sep="")
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the third element is `A` and the fourth is `A2`?

Comment: Can you please explain why for row 3 the new name is A, but for row 7 it's A3?

Comment: Its little bit confusing, as per your description for length > 3 you need to paste A,A2,A3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to create your new column:

```
df$NEWNAME=paste0("A", cumsum(0+df$DIST>=100))
```

I used your data as `df` and also assumed you meant superior *or equal* to 100:

```
df=data.frame("NAME"=rep("A", 9), "DIST"=c(0,1,100,2,1,4,500,1,1))
```

**EDIT**

If you need to start the new names at the row N+1 of the distance>100, you can do this after:

```
df$NEWNAME2 = lag(df$NEWNAME, n=1, default="A0")
####   NAME DIST NEWNAME NEWNAME2
#### 1    A    0      A0       A0
#### 2    A    1      A0       A0
#### 3    A  100      A1       A0
#### 4    A    2      A1       A1
#### 5    A    1      A1       A1
```

Comment: Why the `0+` in the `cumsum()` statement?

Comment: it's just a trick to convert TRUE/FALSE vector to 0/1. well in fact it's not even necessary here because cumsum automatically forces the logical into numeric.

Comment: Thanks. What if I would like to add another constraint, say based on another column?

Comment: @user3910073 of course you would just have to add another condition combined with and/or: `cumsum(df$DIST>=100 & df$NAME=="A")` for example